# override $(element) expression to achieve the same functionality as $(element).length

Tags: jquery

Is it possible what I have mentioned in the title?

I would like to use this for checking existence of an element like so:

```
if($('#item')){...}
```

Any ideas?

That's the code where I use it:

```
if($('#auto_redirect_in_3_s').length)//I "wished" $('#auto_redirect_in_3_s')
    {
        var timer = setTimeout("document.location.href = index_url;",3000);
    }
```

description:
If I put  in php code it means that the page have to redirect in 3 s.

Comment: $('#item').length>0 doesn't works for you?

Comment: it does, but I think this way it would be nicer

Comment: @2astalavista you fundamentally misunderstand how jQuery works if you think you can both have a fluent (chained) interface AND evaluate the results of a selector that doesn't match any elements.  For chaining to work, it *must* return a jQuery object which, because it is non-null, will evaluate to true.  If it were to return null when a selector doesn't match, then any chained calls in that instance would throw an exception because they're invoked on a null object.

Comment: @tvanfosson could you write me an example where the chaining wont work?

Comment: @2astalavista `$('table td > tr').css({ "title": "oops"});` fails if the `$` returns null (since a TD can't have direct child of a TR the selector won't match anything) when it tries to call the `css` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. The `jQuery` factory function (aliased as `$`) returns an instance of a jQuery collection object--even when the selection didn't match anything. If the selector did not match, the collection is empty, but it's still an object so it evaluates to true. You must check `.length` to see if you got anything.

Such checks for `.length`, however, are usually unnecessary given how jQuery works and are often a sign of poor logic or a misunderstanding of jQuery. So if you post your code, we can probably help clean it up.

**Update:**

Ok, your updated question provided the following code:

```
if( $( '#auto_redirect_in_3_s' ).length ) //I "wished" $('#auto_redirect_in_3_s')
{
    var timer = setTimeout( 'document.location.href = index_url;' ,3000 );
}
```

What you're doing isn't terrible and could be considered an Ok usage of `.length`. Allow me, however, to show you a few other ways of accomplishing the same thing. **I am not saying you *should* do any of the following, just showing there are multiple ways to skin a cat, and hopefully show you a little more jQuery usage in some of the examples.**

If you're stuck redirecting a page from the client side instead of with an HTTP header, the best way to accomplish it is with a `meta` tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3; url=http://example.com/">
```

If you desire to keep it in JS you could avoid doing it based on the presence of an element, but on the value held by some input:

```
<input type="hidden" id="auto_redirect_do" value="1" />
<input type="hidden" id="auto_redirect_url" value="http://example.com/" />
<input type="hidden" id="auto_redirect_delay" value="3000" />

<script type="text/javascript>
$( function()
{
    if( $( '#auto_redirect_do' ).val() === '1' )
    {
        window.setTimeout(
            function()
            {
                window.location = $( '#auto_redirect_url' ).val();
            },
            $( '#auto_redirect_delay' ).val()
        );
    }
} );
</script>
```

Or, with a JSON encoded value in an input (or a data attr on an element):

```
<input type="hidden" id="auto_redirect" value="{&quot;do&quot;:true,&quot;url&quot;:&quot;http:\/\/www.example.com&quot;,&quot;delay&quot;:3000}" />

<script type="text/javascript>
$( function()
{
    var auto_direct = JSON.parse( $( '#auto_redirect' ).val() );

    if( auto_direct.do === true )
    {
        window.setTimeout(
            function()
            {
                window.location = auto_redirect.url;
            },
            auto_redirect.delay
        );
    }
} );
</script>
```

Going back to your version of looking for the presence of an element, you could do the following if you wanted to avoid using `.length` and make use of jQuery's chaining:

```
$( '#auto_redirect_in_3_s' ).each( function()
{
    /*
        We got in here because the element was present
    */

    window.setTimeout( function()
    {
        window.location = index_url;
    }, 3000 );

    /* 
        Return false from this function in case we matched more
        than one--no need to setup the redirection multiple times
    */
    return false;
} );
```

Comment: You say I may have a poor logic or I'm misunderstood jquery and I should post the javascript code and you could help clean it up?

Comment: @2astalavista without intending to insult you, yes, that is what I am saying. Given jQuery's chain-able nature and the ability to operate on elements if they exist, but move on quietly if they don't, such checks for `.length` are often unnecessary. That said, there are cases for it and your's could be perfectly legitimate. If you post the code we can take a look and help you if it's not.

Comment: I accept your answer because you made my question unnecessary. Now there is no reason to achieve what I wanted. I have used your first version in php: 
header("refresh:3;url=".$index_url);